# use opencv on heroku with node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, opencv, heroku

I am calling a python script with PythonShell on javascript.

my javascript function is below

```
function runPythonScript(pythonPath, pythonScript) {
  console.log('ND - server - run python without argument');
  let myPath = __dirname;
  console.log('myPath: ', myPath);
  //let pythonPath = pythonPath;
  console.log('pythonPath: ', pythonPath);
  //let pythonScript = pythonScript;
  console.log('pythonScript: ', pythonScript);
 
  //Here are the option object in which arguments can be passed for the python_test.js.
  let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    scriptPath: myPath + pythonPath //If you are having python_test.py script in same folder, then it's optional.
    //args: ['xxxx'] //An argument which can be accessed in the script using sys.argv[1]
  };
 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    PythonShell.run(pythonScript, options, function(err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      // result is an array consisting of messages collected
      //during execution of script.
      console.log('data: ', result.toString());
      let parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.join('\n')));
      console.log('data type: ', typeof parsedData, ' of length ', parsedData.length);
      parsedData = parsedData.replace(/'/g, `"`); // replace the quote by the double quotes for parsing the string to a JSON object.
      parsedData = JSON.parse(parsedData);
      console.log('parsed data type: ', typeof parsedData);
      //console.log('parsed data: ', parsedData);
      resolve(parsedData);
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
    try {
        let counterpartyData = await runPythonScript('/python','test.py');
        console.log('ND - server - counterparty data: ', counterpartyData);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
main();
```

In this function I call the python script here below

```
import cv2

mydict ={
  "counterParty_Car": "Ford",
  "counterParty_CarPlate" : "O XXX YYY",
  "counterParty_Name" : "John Snow",
  "counterParty_Policy": "0123456789"      
}
print(mydict)
```

If i remove the `import cv2` in the python script, there is no error. But if I want to add the import cv2 (because i needed for the next steps). An error appears meaning that there is no module cv2.

```
/app/node_modules/libheif-js/libheif/libheif.js:1
2022-01-12T15:14:56.167971+00:00 app[web.1]: var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};((function(){var 
[...]
```

I tried the answers proposed in other questions and other website but nothing works.
Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

in my `requirment.txt` heroku file, i have `opencv-python-headless==4.5.4.60`

Comment: "in my requirment.txt" -- requir**e**ments.txt ? (if you really made that typo, they'll simply ignore that file) also, check your logs, try the ssh remote console to debug

Comment: also, `PythonShell.run()` might use a different snake than cv2 was installed to ..., please check

Comment: "An error appears meaning that there is no module cv2"—please show us the full, exact error. The error you are showing here is a _JavaScript_ error. We need to see the _Python_ error.